# Why the Storage isn't working on inside a job?

Tags: queue, storage, laravel-5.4, php-7.2

I have some users who need to extract a large amount of data from from the database. I am creating a job that receive the parameters, query the database and write the data on a txt file. And as far as the file is ready I will send a notification e-mail.

To store the file locally, I am using the Storage facade inside the job.

If I run my code on a regular controller, the file is generated, but when I run the same command inside a job, the file is not generated (even having the job processed).

I am running laravel 5.4 on php 7.2. and have linked the storage (php artisan storage:link)

Since my code have a lot of complexity (consulting models, mail and so on) I created a simple test controller and a simple test job to isolate the file creation from the rest of the code. The same problem is happening in the simple version.

Here is the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Storage;
use App\Jobs\testeStorageJob;

class testController extends Controller
{
    public function test(){
        Storage::put('testFile.txt', 'Some Content on a regular controller');
        testeStorageJob::dispatch();
    }
}
```

and here is the job:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Storage;

class testeStorageJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $tries = 1;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Storage::put('testFileQueue.txt', 'Some content on a queue');
    }
}
```

I've checked the filesystem config and it is the default values.

I was expecting to have 2 files on the "Storage/App" folder testFile.txt and testFileQueue.txt, but I only have testFile.txt.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan queue:work`?

Comment: Yes, I tried with the `php artisan queue:work` and `php artisan queue:listen`. None worked...